# SSRS: visibilty of rectangle based on value

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am trying to hide a rectangle in the report, I want to control the visibility of the rectangle based on the `Field!Column.Value`. But in order to set the visibility condition I need to link the rectangle to the data set. Can we link a data set to a rectangle?

I have multiple data sets in the report.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you go to Rectangle Properties -> Visibility -> Show or hide based on an expression [fx]

```
IIF(Fields!SomeField.Value="YourValue", False, True)
```

Comment: When I write the above expression it says report item not linked to data set. I want to know how I can link the rectangle to a data set. Thanks!

Comment: Is your Rectangle within another object? Or is it by itself?

Comment: It is by itself... I have a chart and table inside the rectangle.

Comment: Like I am trying to use the rectangle as a container

Comment: To Directly answer your question above: I don't think you can assign a rectangle to a dataset. However you can place that rectangle inside a list, tablix, etc. and assign that other item a data set. If that helps at all.